# What is a good way to structure mark-up generating code and avoid the example mess?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Here are two methods of code that only vary in one place. Specifically, the first method calls GetReleaseYear(), and the second calls GetReleaseDate().

This is one example of a one-line difference in multiple methods, and each time the difference might be on a different line or couple of lines. One possible design I've considered is passing in a list of strings to a function, but this is cumbersome because the lists would still need to be prepared, and the generated HTML still has to be somewhat content-aware.

```
private string A()
    {
        string title = GetTitle();
        string mediaType = GetMediaType();
        string description = GetDescription();
        string releaseYear = GetReleaseYear();
        string contributors = GetContributors();
        string image = GetImage();
        string genres = GetGenres();
        string ratings = GetRatings();

        string top = string.Format("{0}This is a {1}{2}.<br><br>",
                title, mediaType, string.IsNullOrEmpty(releaseYear) ? string.Empty
                : " released in " + releaseYear);

        StringBuilder metadata = new StringBuilder();
        metadata.AppendLine(contributors + "<br>");
        metadata.AppendLine(genres + "<br><br>");
        metadata.AppendLine(ratings + "<br><br>");
        metadata.AppendLine(description);

        return string.Format("{0}<table><tr><td style=\"width:400px; vertical-align:top\">{1}</td><td style=\"width:400px; vertical-align:top\">{2}</td></tr></table>", top, metadata.ToString(), image);
    }

 private string B()
    {
        string title = GetTitle();
        string mediaType = GetMediaType();
        string description = GetDescription();
        string releaseDate = GetReleaseDate();
        string contributors = GetContributors();
        string image = GetImage();
        string genres = GetGenres();
        string ratings = GetRatings();

        string top = string.Format("{0}This is a {1}{2}.<br><br>",
                title, mediaType, string.IsNullOrEmpty(releaseDate) ? string.Empty
                : " released in " + releaseDate);

        StringBuilder metadata = new StringBuilder();
        metadata.AppendLine(contributors + "<br>");
        metadata.AppendLine(genres + "<br><br>");
        metadata.AppendLine(ratings + "<br><br>");
        metadata.AppendLine(description);

        return string.Format("{0}<table><tr><td style=\"width:400px; vertical-align:top\">{1}</td><td style=\"width:400px; vertical-align:top\">{2}</td></tr></table>", top, metadata.ToString(), image);
    }
```

Comment: get rid of those styles and move them to CSS at the least :)

Comment: @merlin2011 have you considered using a delegate?

Comment: Can the people who are voting to close this question explain why they believe it is off topic?
I am asking this question seriously.

Comment: @dbaseman, I am aware of delegates and used them in the past, but unclear about how they might apply here.

Comment: @M.Babcock The question is not really about improving existing code, because the code hasn't been written yet (outside of one instance of the existing method). It's more about designing code correctly so that when it IS written, it doesn't look like repeated garbage. 
Is it still off-topic in that case?

Comment: @merlin2011 - That is a gray line in my understanding, so I [asked a question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128594/where-is-the-line-between-code-review-and-so-part-2-or-maybe-part-n) for clarification of the rules. It's Saturday night my time so I'm guessing it might be a bit til we get a response. Feel free to add your opinion on the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good practice is `Observe which part of the code does not change` Extract that keep it in a separate method.  Pass the variable `Which changes` as an input to that method.

```
    public string CommonMethod(string formattedString)
    {
        string title = GetTitle();
        string mediaType = GetMediaType();
        string description = GetDescription();
        /***string releaseYear = GetReleaseYear();***/ this is not required.
        string contributors = GetContributors();
        string image = GetImage();
        string genres = GetGenres();
        string ratings = GetRatings();

        string top = **formattedString**;

        StringBuilder metadata = new StringBuilder();
        metadata.AppendLine(contributors + "<br>");
        metadata.AppendLine(genres + "<br><br>");
        metadata.AppendLine(ratings + "<br><br>");
        metadata.AppendLine(description);

        return string.Format("{0}<table><tr><td style=\"width:400px; vertical-align:top\">{1}</td><td style=\"width:400px; vertical-align:top\">{2}</td></tr></table>", top, metadata.ToString(), image);
    }
```

***each time the difference might be on a different line or couple of lines.***

This part is difficult to answer. Even in that scenario, omit the one or two lines which may change, pass the things which may change as input.

Answer (score 2):

There's no one answer for all situations, and your code didn't indicate what the class structures involved might be.

Here are some options:

- implement a GetReleaseValue(boolean fullDate) function, and have it
  call either GetReleaseDate() or GetReleaseYear() depending on the
  variable passed in.  Then merge A() and B() into AB(boolean
  fullDate), and have it call GetReleaseValue(fullDate).
- if GetReleaseDate() and GetReleaseYear() are from a class, you could
  create a subclass and either override GetReleaseDate() to just return
  a year (depending on the datatypes) or else make a new method
  GetReleaseValue() which delegates to the correct function depending
  on which class you're in.  Then you just have to instantiate the
  right class before calling AB().
- delegates can be used:  this allows you to pass a function in to another function, so you'd make your new method AB(delegate releaseValue), and instead of calling GetReleaseYear/Date() you'd call the delegate method releaseValue().